# block per grid allocation habit in cuda

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

There is one common habit I saw in cuda example when they allocation the grid size. The following is an example:

```
int 
main(){

    ...
    int numElements = 50000;
    int threadsPerBlock = 1024;
    int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

    vectorAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, numElements);
    ...
}

__global__ void
vectorAdd(const float *A, const float *B, float *C, int numElements)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < numElements)
    {
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
}
```

What I am curious about is the initialization of blocksPerGrid. I don't understand why it's

```
int blocksPerGrid = (numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
```

rather than straightforward

```
int blocksPerGrid = numElements / threadsPerblock;
```

It seems it's a quite common habit. I saw in various projects. They all do this in this way.
I am new to cuda. Any explanation or knowledge behind this are welcomed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The calculation is done the way you see to allow for cases where `numElements` isn't a round multiple of `threadsPerblock`.

For example, using `threadsPerblock = 256` and `numElements = 500`

```
(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock = (500 + 255) / 256 = 2
```

whereas

```
numElements / threadsPerblock = 500 / 256 = 1
```

In the first case, 512 threads are run, covering the 500 elements in the input data, but in the second case, only 256 threads are run, leaving 244 input items unprocessed.

Note also this kind of "guard" code in the kernel:

```
int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

if (i < numElements)
{
    ... Access input here
}
```

is essential to prevent any of the extra threads from  performing out of bounds memory operations.